# Removing the allowed space for the date in beamer

Tags: date, latex, beamer

I'm making a beamer presentation and I would like to delete the reserved space for the date to make my title graphic closer to the title.

I tried `\date{}` but this keeps the white space where date appears if I choose a date.

Is it possible to remove this space?

Comment: Please always include a [mre] in your question so people looking into them have a test file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With beamer v3.70 or later, you can redefine the `date` template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{names}
\title{text}
\titlegraphic{title graphic}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could even add some negative space if you'd like the title graphic to be even closer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{names}
\title{text}
\titlegraphic{title graphic}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{\vskip-0.5cm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```